# What is the most efficent way to animate without intersecting?

Tags: animation, objects, path

[Beginner here]

What is the best way to animate these without the objects intersecting each other?

At the moment my objects intersect with the ground and each other. I am trying to avoid manual keyframing as much as possible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't want manual keyframing, the only possibility would be rigid body simulation I guess. But since the objects will not fall upwards to reach the position where they should end, you should start with the end position and simulate them falling down. Then bake the animation (of course you have lots of keyframes then) and reverse it. Or render it running forward and align the rendered images in a reversed order. Of course the simulation will not move the bottom cube for example the way it's moving now.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank you for your response. The trouble is I used physics rendering just before this scene, the the placement of the objects at the beginning of the GIF is already physics calculated, so I can't reverse the physics.

Comment: You can always take objects in the end position, remove all physics and start simulating again. But what I don't understand: if you used physics to get them in this position, why didn't you take that simulation for non-overlapping movements?

Comment: How do you do that? If I keyframe dynamic to animated the object jumps back to the original position.

Comment: First of all I mean, when you simulated them to get into that start position, why are they now overlapping at all? You could have used that simulation. The other thing is, if you move to the end position, then remove all keyframes and rigid bodies, you have them in the end position and can now simulate them falling down again.

Comment: I added another GIF to show the beginning. I used physics to get them to the first static position - but I wasn't able to animate their position from there, so I duplicated the object and turned off the previous physics-rendered shape, and carried on from there.